# Функция метод Show() не работает в C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class String
{
private:
char *str;
int len;
public:
String(const char *s);
String();
String(const String &st);
~String();
int length() const { return len; }
String &operator=(const String &st);
String &operator=(const char *s);
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const String &st);
friend istream &operator>>(istream &is, String &st);
};
String::String(const char *s)
{
    len = strlen(s);
    str = new char[len + 1];
    strcpy(str, s);
}
String::String()
{
    len = 0;
    str = new char[1];
    str[0] = '\0';
}
String::String(const String &st)
{
    len = st.len;
    str = new char[len + 1];
    strcpy(str, st.str);
}
String::~String()
{
    delete []str;
}
String &String::operator=(const String &st)
{
    if(this == &st) return *this;
    delete []str;
    len = st.len;
    str = new char[len + 1];
    strcpy(str, st.str);
    return *this;
}
String &String::operator=(const char *s)
{
    delete []str;
    len = strlen(s);
    str = new char[len + 1];
    strcpy(str, s);
    return *this;
}
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const String &st)
{
    os << st.str;
    return os;
}
istream &operator>>(istream &is, String &st)
{
    char temp[80];
    is.get(temp, 80);
    if(is) st = temp;
    while(is && is.get() != '\n')
    continue;
    return is;
}
class ArrayDb
{
private:
unsigned int size;
double *arr;
public:
ArrayDb();
explicit ArrayDb(unsigned int n, double val = 0.0);
ArrayDb(const double *pn, unsigned int n);
ArrayDb(const ArrayDb &a);
virtual ~ArrayDb();
unsigned int ArSize() const { return size; }
double Average() const;
virtual double &operator[](int i);
virtual const double &operator[](int i) const;
ArrayDb &operator=(const ArrayDb &a);
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const ArrayDb &a);
};
ArrayDb::ArrayDb()
{
    arr = NULL;
    size = 0;
}
ArrayDb::ArrayDb(unsigned int n, double val)
{
    arr = new double[n];
    size = n;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) arr[i] = val;
}
ArrayDb::ArrayDb(const double *pn, unsigned int n)
{
    arr = new double[n];
    size = n;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) arr[i] = pn[i];
}
ArrayDb::ArrayDb(const ArrayDb &a)
{
    size = a.size;
    arr = new double[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) arr[i] = a.arr[i];
}
ArrayDb::~ArrayDb()
{
    delete []arr;
}
double ArrayDb::Average() const
{
    double sum = 0;
    int i;
    int lim = ArSize();
    for(i = 0; i < lim; i++) sum += arr[i];
    if(i > 0) return sum / i;
    else{
        cerr << "No data in Average.\n";
        return 0;
    }
}
double &ArrayDb::operator[](int i)
{
    if(i < 0 || i >= size)
    {
        cerr << "Error in array limits: " << i << " is a bad index\n";
    }
    return arr[i];
}
const double &ArrayDb::operator[](int i) const
{
    if(i < 0 || i >= size)
    {
        cerr << "Error in array limits: " << i << " is a bad index\n";
    }
    return arr[i];
}
ArrayDb &ArrayDb::operator=(const ArrayDb &a)
{
    if(this == &a) return *this;
    delete []arr;
    size = a.size;
    arr = new double[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) arr[i] = a.arr[i];
    return *this;
}
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const ArrayDb &a)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < a.size; i++)
    {
        os << a.arr[i] << " ";
        if(i % 5 == 4) os << endl;
    }
    if(i % 5 != 0) os << endl;
    return os;
}
class Worker
{
private:
String fullname;
long id;
protected:
virtual void Data() const;
virtual void Get();
public:
Worker() : fullname("no one"), id(0L) { }
Worker(const String &s, long n) : fullname(s), id(n) {}
virtual ~Worker() = 0;
virtual void Set() = 0;
virtual void Show() const = 0;
};
class Waiter: virtual public Worker
{
private:
int panache;
protected:
void Data() const;
void Get();
public:
Waiter() : Worker(), panache(0) {}
Waiter(const String &s, long n, int p = 0) : Worker(s, n), panache(p) {}
Waiter(const Worker &wk, int p = 0) : Worker(wk), panache(p) { }
void Set();
void Show() const;
};
class Singer : virtual public Worker
{
protected:
enum{other, alto, contralto, soprano, bass, baritone, tenor};
enum{ Vtypes = 7};
void Data() const;
void Get();
private:
static char *pv[Vtypes];
int voice;
public:
Singer() : Worker(), voice(other) { }
Singer(const String &s, long n, int v = other) : Worker(s, n), voice(v) { }
Singer(const Worker &wk, int v = other) : Worker(wk), voice(v) {}
void Set();
void Show() const;
};
class SingingWaiter : public Singer, public Waiter
{
protected:
void Data() const;
void Get();
public:
SingingWaiter() {}
SingingWaiter(const String &s, long n, int p = 0, int v = Singer::other) : Worker(s, n), Waiter(s, n, p), Singer(s, n, v) {}
SingingWaiter(const Worker &wk, int p = 0, int v = Singer::other) : Worker(wk), Waiter(wk, p), Singer(wk, v) {}
SingingWaiter(const Waiter &wt, int v = other) : Worker(wt), Waiter(wt), Singer(wt, v) {}
SingingWaiter(const Singer &sg, int p = 0) : Worker(sg), Waiter(sg, p), Singer(sg) {}
void Set();
void Show() const;
};
Worker::~Worker() {}
void Worker::Data() const
{
    cout << "Name: " << fullname << endl;
    cout << "Employee ID: " << id << endl;
}
void Worker::Get()
{
    cin >> fullname;
    cout << "Enter worker's ID: ";
    cin >> id;
    while(cin.get() != '\n') continue;
}
void Waiter::Set()
{
    cout << "Enter waiter's name: ";
    Worker::Get();
    Get();
}
void Waiter::Show() const
{
    cout << "Category: waiter\n";
    Worker::Data();
    Data();
}
void Waiter::Data() const
{
    cout << "Panache rating: " << panache << endl;
}
void Waiter::Get()
{
    cout << "Enter waiters's panache rating: ";
    cin >> panache;
    while(cin.get() != '\n')continue;
}
char *Singer::pv[Singer::Vtypes] = { "other", "alto", "contralto", "soprano", "bass", "baritone", "tenor"};
void Singer::Set()
{
    cout << "Enter singer's name: ";
    Worker::Get();
    Get();
}
void Singer::Show() const
{
    cout << "Category: singer\n";
    Worker::Data();
    Data();
}
void Singer::Data() const
{
    cout << "Vocal range: " << pv[voice] << endl;
}
void Singer::Get()
{
    cout << "Enter number for singer's vocal range: ";
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < Vtypes; i++)
    {
        cout << i << ": " << pv[i] << "    ";
        if(i % 4 == 3) cout << endl;
    }
    if(i %4 != 0) cout << endl;
    cin >> voice;
    while(cin.get() != '\n') continue;
}
void SingingWaiter::Data() const
{
    Singer::Data();
    Waiter::Data();
}
void SingingWaiter::Get()
{
    Waiter::Get();
    Singer::Get();
}
void SingingWaiter::Set()
{
    cout << "Enter singing waiter's name: ";
    Worker::Get();
    Get();
}
void SingingWaiter::Show() const
{
    cout << "Category: singing waiter\n";
    Worker::Data();
    Data();
}
template <class T, int n>
class QueueTp
{
private:
T ar[n];
public:
QueueTp();
explicit QueueTp(const T &v);
virtual T &operator[](int i);
virtual const T &operator[](int i) const;
};
template <class T, int n>
QueueTp<T,n>::QueueTp()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) ar[i] = 0;
}
template <class T, int n>
QueueTp<T, n>::QueueTp(const T &v)
{
    ar[0] = v;
}
template <class T, int n>
T & QueueTp<T, n>::operator[](int i)
{
    if(i < 0 || i >= n)
    {
        cout << "You cant return less than 0 or more than limit!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    return ar[i];
}
template <class T, int n>
const T &QueueTp<T, n>::operator[](int i) const
{
    if(i < 0 || i >= n)
    {
        cout << "You cant return less than 0 or more than limit!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    return ar[i];
}
int main()
{
    Worker *lolas[5];
    int ct;
    for(ct = 0; ct < 5; ct++)
    {
        char choice;
        cout << "Enter the employee category:\n" <<
        "w: waiter, s: singer, t: singingwaiter, q: quit\n";
        cin >> choice;
        while(strchr("ewstq", choice) == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a w, s, t or q: ";
            cin >> choice;
        } 
        if(choice == 'q') break;
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 'w': lolas[ct] = new Waiter; break;
            case 's': lolas[ct] = new Singer; break;
            case 't': lolas[ct] = new SingingWaiter; break;
        }
        cin.get();
        lolas[ct]->Set();
        cout << "Here is your staff:\n";
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < ct; i++)
        {
            cout << endl;
            lolas[i]->Show();
        }
        for(i = 0; i < ct; i++) delete lolas[i];
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Доброго дня(или ночи), суть программы это работа с MI Singer и Waiter наследуются(виртуально) от абстрактного базового класса(Worker) Worker содержит имя человека и ID, а singer оценивает голос и waiter оценивает что то через переменную int, но самое главное это производный класс SinginWaiter который содержит Singer и Waiter(и подобъект Worker) SingingWaiter это просто объединение Singer и Waiter, и также есть класс QeueuTp который работает с шаблоном, в main я написал QueueTp<Worker *, 5> lolas для того чтобы создать 5 массивов Worker и инициализировать их после инициализации надо показать инфо о объекте (lolas[i]->Show()) в цикле но она не показывается и программа прекращается сразу во время Show(), в чем проблема?

Comment: в С++ нету метода такого, правильно формулируйте вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментарий не влезу...

разбираем по кусочкам.

```
for(ct = 0; ct < 5; ct++)
{
```

Пошла первая итерация `ct == 0`. Вы что-то там ввели, и пришли сюда:

```
    cout << "Here is your staff:\n";
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < ct; i++)  
    {
```

Так как `ct == 0`, цикл не выполняется

```
        cout << endl;
        lolas[i]->Show();
    }
```

и переходим сюда

```
    for(i = 0; i < ct; i++) delete lolas[i];
    return 0;
```

А тут - см. `return` - программа завершается.

Всё, как вы пишете, так и работает. `Show()` не вызывается, программа завершается...